# issue creating .PFX file using keytool.exe

Tags: java

I've just downloaded Java and have created a keystore file (.ks) and certificate (.cer), and now want to create a .PFX using the .ks file. However, when I type the below at a command prompt, i get the error message shown.

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\clien
ts\Client.ks -srcstorepass Password1 -destkeystore c:\private key file\Testfile.pf
x -deststorepass Password1 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias Testfile
Illegal option:  key
keytool -importkeystore [OPTION]...

Imports one or all entries from another keystore

Options:

 -srckeystore <srckeystore>            source keystore name
 -destkeystore <destkeystore>          destination keystore name
 -srcstoretype <srcstoretype>          source keystore type
 -deststoretype <deststoretype>        destination keystore type
 -srcstorepass <arg>                   source keystore password
 -deststorepass <arg>                  destination keystore password
 -srcprotected                         source keystore password protected
 -srcprovidername <srcprovidername>    source keystore provider name
 -destprovidername <destprovidername>  destination keystore provider name
 -srcalias <srcalias>                  source alias
 -destalias <destalias>                destination alias
 -srckeypass <arg>                     source key password
 -destkeypass <arg>                    destination key password
 -noprompt                             do not prompt
 -providerclass <providerclass>        provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>                    provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>              provider classpath
 -v                                    verbose output

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2.

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

your option `-destkeystore c:\private key file\Testfile.pfx` contains a path with whitespaces which isn't valid in this context

this is why the word **key** is interpreted as an option, which obviously isn't a valid option

fix your path and the problem should be fixed